# Show a second select box based on the option chosen in the first?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have the following select drop down box:

```
      <select name="selectcourier" required>
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="collection">Collection</option>
        <option value="Interlink">Interlink</option>
        <option value="DespatchBay">Despatch Bay</option>
        <option value="International">International</option>
      </select>
```

What I want to do is if Interlink is selected a secondary select box appears below it and disappears if it unselected and another option is chosen instead. This is the second select drop down box.

```
     <label>Select Shipping Courier:</label>
     <select name="selectcourier" required>
        <option value="1">Please Select</option>
        <option value="2">Next Day</option>
        <option value="3">2-3 Day</option>
        <option value="3">Pre 12</option>
     </select>
```

How can I go about getting this working?

Comment: If it unselected means?

Answer (score 1):

bind an event with javascript on change and insert a new element in the DOM (the second select statement) like:

(provided you have jquery)

```
    var secondSelect="your_html_here";

    $("name='selectcourier'").change(function() { 
        if (this.val()=='Interlink') {
            $('body').append(secondSelect); }
        else { 
             $('#secondselectid').remove();
        });
```

customise the html and where you want to append the second select

Comment: downvote happened automagically milliseconds after my answer. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#s1').hide();

});
function call()
{

        var check=$('#s2').val();
    if(check=="Interlink")
        {
        $('#s1').show();
        }
```

else
        {
        $('#s1').hide();
        }

```
    }
</script>


<select name="selectcourier" required onchange="call();" id="s2" >
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="collection">Collection</option>
        <option value="Interlink">Interlink</option>
        <option value="DespatchBay">Despatch Bay</option>
        <option value="International">International</option>
      </select> 
      <label>Select Shipping Courier:</label>
     <select name="selectcourier" required id="s1">
        <option value="1">Please Select</option>
        <option value="2">Next Day</option>
        <option value="3">2-3 Day</option>
        <option value="3">Pre 12</option>
     </select>
```

You can use the above code to achieve your task

Answer (score 1):

Just react on the event of changing the value of the first select.

If the value equals **'Interlink'** display the second select - if the value is something else hide the second select.

```
<select name="selectcourier" required onchange="document.getElementById('interlink_addition').style.display = (this.value=='Interlink' ? 'block' : 'none')">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="collection">Collection</option>
  <option value="Interlink">Interlink</option>
  <option value="DespatchBay">Despatch Bay</option>
  <option value="International">International</option>
</select>
<div id="interlink_addition" style="display:none">
  <label>Select Shipping Courier:</label>
  <select name="selectcourier" required>
     <option value="1">Please Select</option>
     <option value="2">Next Day</option>
     <option value="3">2-3 Day</option>
     <option value="3">Pre 12</option>
  </select> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax for this. write a ajax function to show second select box and call it on onChange event of the first select Box