# Showing 2th dropdown when dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript

When i select an item on select box(whose option value is "il"), should be displayed hidden 2st select box(ilce).. thanks in advance.

```
 <select name="il" id="il" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="il">Seçin...</option>
            </select>
  <br>
      
            <select name="ilce" id="ilce" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" required>
                <option value="">Seçin...</option>
            </select>
```

```
    $.getJSON("il-bolge.json", function(sonuc){
        $.each(sonuc, function(index, value){
            var row="";
            row +='<option value="'+value.il+'">'+value.il+'</option>';
            $("#il").append(row);
        })
    });


    $("#il").on("change", function(){
        var il=$(this).val();

        $("#ilce").attr("disabled", false).html("<option value=''>Seçin..</option>");
        $.getJSON("il-ilce.json", function(sonuc){
            $.each(sonuc, function(index, value){
                var row="";
                if(value.il==il)
                {
                    row +='<option value="'+value.ilce+'">'+value.ilce+'</option>';
                    $("#ilce").append(row);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show a second select box based on the option chosen in the first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664040/show-a-second-select-box-based-on-the-option-chosen-in-the-first)

Comment: may, Can you integrate the link you sent into my project?